# Shoot Arrow in the direction that the Bow is facing

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a iOS Game where a player has a bow and arrow that spins in a 360 degree circle, and the player must shoot the bow at the right time to hit the target. Right now I am having trouble getting the arrow to shoot *in the direction* the bow is facing, as well as getting the arrow to shoot at the *right angle* towards that direction.

```
      let bullet = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "Bullet")
      bullet?.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
      bullet.zPosition = -5

      bullet.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x, player.position.y)
      bullet.zRotation = player.zRotation


      let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 0.8)
      let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
      bullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

      bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.size)
      bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
      bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
      self.addChild(bullet)
```

The player refers the the bow for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the bullet to `self.size.height + 30` in the Y direction and 0 pixels in the X direction, you can rotate that movement direction by the `zRotation` using trigonometry.

```
let amount = self.size.height + 30
let action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(bullet.position.x + amount * sin(bullet.zRotation), bullet.position.y + amount * cos(bullet.zRotation)), duration: 0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the behavior you are looking for by calculating a force vector from the bullet's `zRotation` and then use it to apply a force to the bullet's `physicsBody`.

To do this we will use trigonometry.

```
//adjust rotation by pi/2 radians to match spriteKits rotation system
let adjustedRotation = bullet.zRotation + .pi/2

//intensity scalar
let intensity:CGFloat = 4000 //adjust this value

//find x and y components using adjustedRotation and scale by intensity
let vx = intensity * cos(adjustedRotation)
let vy = intensity * sin(adjustedRotation)

//make vector using vx and vy components
let forceVector = CGVector(dx:vx, dy: vy)

//apply force to physicsBody
bullet.physicsBody?.applyForce(forceVector)
```

Comment: You don't need to adjust the angle if the bullet/arrow image points to the right.

Comment: @0x141E Testing in Xcode shows the correct results even when pointing to the right using the code as written.

Comment: If you view the pic of your bullet in the Preview app (or in Xcode's Navigator), which direction does it point?

Comment: @0x141E I misunderstood what you were saying. You are correct in saying that if the arrow image is pointing to the right then the angle wouldn’t need to be adjusted. My mistake.